# Get Post ID just after adding Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I get the id of a post that I just created ?? Like we do in PHP mysql_insert_id() Thx !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's returned by the same API call you use to make the post - in Javascript use a callback function, in PHP it'll be returned by the $facebook->api() call; using any other SDK it'll depend on how you wrapped the call to the API.

Comment: Thx ,can You give me an example PLZ

Comment: Er, `$post_id = $facebook->api('/me/feed?message=test');` then `echo $post_id` should do it